# How do I fix the NameError in my python lottery

Tags: python, nameerror

I am making a dictionary and I set up a variable string thing inside the dictionary and it's "numbers" and when I tried to pull the information it gave me a NameError saying it wasn't defined and I'm too stupid to figure it out.

```
x = {"player_1":"Player 1", "numbers":{2,5,4,43,12,24}}
x_1 = {"player_2":"Player 2", "numbers":{12,14,23,35,15,6}}
x_2 = {"player_3":"Player 3", "numbers":{32,2,65,35,32}}
x_3= {"player_4":"Player 4", "numbers":{24,23,26,58,27}}

for playername in x:
    inter_var = len(this_dict[numbers].intersection(playername))
    top_player = playername
 
    if inter_var > len(top_player[numbers].intersection(lottery_numbers)):
        print(f"{top_player} won {winnings}")
```

Comment: `this_dict`, contrary to its name, is *not* a dictionary but rather a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Scott Hunter, Thanks I'll try that!

Comment: Make a [mcve], with sample input and expected vs. actual output.  What do you think `inter_var` is supposed to calculate?

Comment: @user22881646 Now you edited your question to show us worse code than before. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your goal is, but you should start with something like the following, with consistent keys and a goal like counting matching numbers:

```py
players = [{'name': 'Player 1', 'numbers': { 2,  5,  4, 43, 12, 24}},
           {'name': 'Player 2', 'numbers': {12, 14, 23, 35, 15,  6}},
           {'name': 'Player 3', 'numbers': {31,  2, 65, 35, 32, 12}},
           {'name': 'Player 4', 'numbers': {24, 23, 26, 58, 27,  7}}]

lottery_numbers = { 2, 5, 4, 43, 12, 1}

for player in players:
    count = len(player['numbers'].intersection(lottery_numbers))
    print(f"{player['name']} matched {count} numbers.")
```

Output:

```
Player 1 matched 5 numbers.
Player 2 matched 1 numbers.
Player 3 matched 2 numbers.
Player 4 matched 0 numbers.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already iterating over the `list` of `dictionaries` using your for-loop. In your for-loop, `playername` is each dictionary, so you could just write

```py
playername["numbers"]
```

if you want to access the numbers for each player.

As a sidenote, it looks like you're taking the intersection between the set of numbers and the dictionary, which I don't think is a desired behaviour (this will always result in the empty set).